# What's the simplest way to load a file through localhost?

Tags: localhost

Sorry if I am being naive. I can write websites but do not know much about servers.

I have a single file which connects to a 3rd party database via their API which they only allow from localhost.

I can have the file to use only inline HTML/CSS and JS so will not need PHP (although would be easier if did), and can load the file myself on my own environment as I have a server set up.

However, I would like other users to be able to see the file. As they need to load the file from localhost for the API, would they need to set up a webserver?

A few options I have found are my users would need to install their own webserver, or if using windows they can configure IIS through their control panel.

Is there anything on most common computers or browsers which can allow the file to be loaded via localhost using default configurations or will my users need to download/configure something on their own personal computer?

If there is no default option what would be easiest for users who are not developers or technical, could an exe file create an application which can load the file through localhost, or again would this need the user to configure anything?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have a hosting somewhere and you load the file on their(hosting service) server, it would be loading from localhost because it would be on that server.  Then it would be accessible to everyone if you point it to a public domain name.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: For instance, when I have a site on my hosting plan and I connect to it with mysql, I use `localhost` for the host to point the mysql credentials at.

Comment: Can you share the 3rd party API documentation link so I can read what you are talking about?